# How can I place a UIView overlay above a modal view?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an informative overlay that I want to apply above a view controller presented as a modal. I've attempted all sorts of hacks to get the overlay (a transparent UIView) to be shown above the modal view controller without any luck.

The only thing that has had some success is adding the overlay as a subview of the main UIWindow but that negates a number of helpful features that the UIWindow provides (such as a rotation-independent coordinate system).

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does your informative overlay extend beyond the borders of the modal view?

Comment: @colbadhombre Yes, it extends to the screen bounds.

Comment: Then I think you'll have to polish your original approach, come up with a non-modal solution, or fake something that looks like a modal view so you could paint across it in a single view (ick). The answer from @jakraska below is correct, modal is on top by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats kind of the whole point of a modal view - its on top.  The only think i can think of would be to add it as a subview of the modal view.  This may require you to subclass the modal view and add in extra functionality there depending on what your actually working with

Answer (score 0):

One idea that pops into mind is this:

Put your transparent overlay over the main view, launch your modal popover, add the transparent overlay again to your modal popover, but offset it's origin so that just that part of it that's needed to show within the popover space will line up with the overlay that's over the main view.

You might have an issue with getting the shading correct, but seems like it would be quick to try.  Only downside I can visualize is that the borders of the popover might block some of it out.